# Movie where a boy finds a talking alien powersuit and gets inside

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

Never actually got the name of this movie and only saw it randomly on telly once.

What I remember is this alien race fighting a war lost a super powerful sentient powersuit on Earth, then this random kid finds it and gets inside. Shenanigans then ensue.

I remember the suit would talk to the kid through a weird face on the inside and the kid tries to teach it the meaning of fun, the suit faked that it was about to blow up in a bad first try at a joke.

There were also pitfalls in eating where they got a burger from a drive-thru on the rocket skates mode (of course) and the suit compressed it down into a weird ball, then when the kid needed to pee it turned out the alien it was made for goes through a nozzle on the chest so he has to go ask his schoolteacher to somehow bodge it so he can go.

Then evil alien shows up and there's some fight in fairground, where the kid saves his crush from a broken space themed ride, and tries to fight the alien by turning the suit's hands into hammers.

The movie ends with alien getting blown up and the suit getting handed off to good guy aliens, as it tells a slightly better joke.

Comment: In roughly which year did you see this movie, and when do you think it might've been made?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Sounds like ***[Star Kid](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120478/)*** (1997).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Kid):

> *Star Kid* (originally titled *The Warrior of Waverly Street*) is a 1997 independent superhero film directed and written by Manny Coto and starring Joseph Mazzello, Richard Gilliland, and Corinne Bohrer.

> **Shy seventh-grader Spencer Griffith has a crush on a schoolmate named Michelle. His life changes one night when a mysterious meteorite crashes into a nearby junkyard. Sneaking out of his house to investigate the site, he discovers the meteorite to actually be a small rocket carrying a "Cyborsuit.", a prototype exoskeletal-suit with AI (short for Artificial intelligence) from another galaxy. He decides to try it on and melds with it**, but requires some time to adjust to the experience, including the new speed and strength. He then tests out the suit's various primary functions and abilities, deciding to call it "Cy". He proceeds to go around town doing whatever he wants, starting with getting back at a bully from school named Turbo, then saving Michelle and her friends from a damaged Rock-O-Plane and **ordering food from a fast-food restaurant drive-thru**. He also endures the hilarious antics of trashing part of his house after getting his head stuck inside the refrigerator, discovering the unappealing way that the suit will allow him to eat his ordered drive-thru food, and finding a way to pee when Cy won't let him out to do it.

You can see a talking face on the inside of the suit at the [0:37](https://youtu.be/gr6CoJ6sLz8?t=37) mark in the trailer below, and the Wikipedia summary mentions that he orders fast food from a drive-thru.

Comment: Beat me to it, this checks out from what I remember of the film

Comment: Yup nailed it in one

Comment: Yes, I thought it was Star Kid just from reading the title.